# Не получается отправлять пользователю письмо со значениями произвольных полей

Tags: php, wordpress, email

Пытаюсь админу после того, как пользователь подписался на курс отправить данные курса, но почему-то приходят пустые значения, подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть причина?
Вот результат того, что приходит на почту админу.
На вашем сайте была оформлена подписка на курс:

Номер заказа: #976

Название курса:
Стоимость заказа:
Статус заказа:
Студент:

Вместо get_field пытался поставить get_post_meta, результат тот же.
Попытался сделать всё, что предложил Pyramidhead , но результат такой же .... не отправляются значения кастом филдов.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_project_updated_send_email' );
function my_project_updated_send_email( $post_id ) {

        if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) || get_post($post_id)->post_status != 'publish' )
            return;

        $post_title = get_the_title( $post_id );

        $course_name = get_field('course_name',$post_id,false);

        $order_status =  get_field('order_status',$post_id,false);

        $order_price = get_field('order_cost',$post_id,false);

        $subject = 'Новая подписка на курс была создана';

        $message = "На вашем сайте была оформлена подписка на курс:\n\n";
        $message .= "Номер заказа: " . $post_title . "\n" .  "Название курса: " . $course_name . "\n" . "Стоимость заказа: " .$order_price . "\n" . "Статус заказа: " . $order_status ;

        wp_mail( get_option('admin_email'), $subject, $message );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, всё не так сложно, как казалось )
Решилось это тем, что на момент отправления письма, кастом филды ещё не были заполнены в посте.

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post($post_data);
        update_field('order_cost', $price, $post_id);
        update_field('order_status', 0, $post_id);
        update_field('course_name', $course_name, $post_id);
        do_action('acf/save_post' , $post_id);
        wp_update_post(array('ID' => $post_id, 'post_title' => "#$post_id"));
```

Спасибо всем за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, дело в том, что в момент вызова функции `get_field` плагин Advanced Custom Fields ещё не сохранил эти данные этих полей и поэтому возвращается пустое значение. Попробуйте получать значения напрямую из массива `$_POST`:

```
$course_name = $_POST['acf']['field_course_name'];
$order_status =  $_POST['acf']['field_order_status'];
$order_price = $_POST['acf']['field_order_cost'];
```

Или же измените приоритет вызова вашей функции:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_project_updated_send_email', 20 );
```

Comment: к сожалению, не помогло.....и дальше пустые поля приходят.

Comment: @Nick, дополнил ответ. Попробуйте изменить приоритет вызова вашей функции.

Comment: приоритет тоже изменил - не помогло. самое интересное что если в админке создаю, либо же редактирую пост - то данные приходят корректные : На вашем сайте была оформлена подписка на курс:

Номер заказа: #978
Название курса: «Первый шаг в музыкальное искусство», подготовительный шестимесячный курс - 127грн. / 182 дня
Стоимость заказа: 1278
Статус заказа: 1

Comment: я уже и не знаю как это поправить, пол дня сегодня промучался с этим...

Comment: Попробуйте так: `$course_name = $_POST['acf']['field_course_name'];
$order_status =  $_POST['acf']['field_order_status'];
$order_price = $_POST['acf']['field_order_cost'];`.
Также, возможно, стоит использовать хук `acf/save_post` вместо `save_post`

Comment: при данном хуке письмо вообще не приходит почему-то

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `get_field`, но ещё уменьшить приоритет вызова вашей функции. Например так: `add_action( 'save_post', 'my_project_updated_send_email', 9999 );`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70034/discussion-between-nick-and-pyramidhead).